# how do i create main and sub levels of textboxes in a row on button click and get their values

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, textbox

my code is generating a row of three textboxes each time when i click add button, but these are main levels of textboxes. i also want to create sub levels of each main level on another button click and get their values

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

   {
        CreateTextBoxes();

    }
```

createTextBoxes() method will create textboxes on page load.

```
private void CreateTextBoxes()
    {
        int count = int.Parse(hdnCount.Value);

        // Recreate the textboxes on each postback
        for (int i = 2; i <= count; i++)
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.ID = "txtName" + i.ToString();
            tb.Width = 200;
            tb.Text = Request.Form["txtName" + i.ToString()];
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            TableCell tc = new TableCell();

            tc.Controls.Add(tb);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            tblMain.Rows.Add(tr);

            TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
            tb1.ID = "txtName2" + i.ToString();
            tb1.Width = 200;
            tb1.Text = Request.Form["txtName2" + i.ToString()];

            TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
            tc1.Controls.Add(tb1);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc1);
            tblMain.Rows.Add(tr);


            TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
            tb2.ID = "txtName3" + i.ToString();
            tb2.Width = 200;
            tb2.Text = Request.Form["txtName3" + i.ToString()];

            TableCell tc2 = new TableCell();
            tc2.Controls.Add(tb2);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc2);
            tblMain.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
    }
```

on button click this code add a row of three textboxes which is my main level.

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = int.Parse(hdnCount.Value);
        count++;
        hdnCount.Value = count.ToString();

        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "txtName" + count.ToString();
        tb.Width = 200;
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        tc.Controls.Add(tb);
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        tblMain.Rows.Add(tr);

        TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
        tb1.ID = "txtName2" + count.ToString();
        tb1.Width = 200;
        TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
        tc1.Controls.Add(tb1);
        tr.Cells.Add(tc1);
        tblMain.Rows.Add(tr);


        TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
        tb2.ID = "txtName3" + count.ToString();

        tb2.Width = 200;

        TableCell tc2 = new TableCell();
        tc2.Controls.Add(tb2);
        tr.Cells.Add(tc2);
        tblMain.Rows.Add(tr);
    }
```

Comment: plz help me in this matter

Comment: dynamic controls are a pain to be used with asp.net. recreating controls an d also saving the values on each postback is exhausting. I just used a data list to create dynamic controls

Comment: can u show me how did u do this ? @Mysterio11